# The number of T-invariant subspaces in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is an exercise in Advanced Linear Algebra, Cooperstein.

Assume $T$ is a cyclic operator on $\mathbb{R^3}$.  Let $N$ be the number of $T$-invariant subspaces.  Prove that $N \in \{4,6,8\}$.

An operator $T$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ (over field $\mathbb{F}$) is a cyclic operator if there is a vector $v \in V$ such that $V = \{f(T)v:f(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]\}$.

The annihilator ideal of $T$ on $V$, denoted $Ann(T)$, is the ideal $\{f(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]:f(T)v =0 \  \forall v \in V \}$.  In other words, $Ann(T) = \{f(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]:f(T)=0_{V \to V} \}$ where $0_{V \to V}$ is the zero operator on $V$.

The minimal polynomial of $T$, denoted $\mu_T(x)$, is the unique monic polynomial of least degree in $Ann(T)$.

The hint in the solutions section says to consider the possibilities for $\mu_T(x)$ and that there are four cases to consider.

The subsequent exercise in the text asks for an example of a cyclic operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has exactly four subspaces that are $T$-invariant.

Comment: Please give the definition of cyclic operator and describe the four cases for the minimum polynomial.

Comment: @ZachTeitler I think part of the exercise is to come up with those four cases, i.e. that's what the user was asking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider only the NON-TRIVAL $T$-invariant subspaces over $\mathbb{R}$; we show that there are $2,4,$ or $6$ such subspaces. In the sequel, $[u],[u,v]$ denote the vector-spaces spanned by $u$ or $u,v$.

Since $T$ is cyclic, $T$ is similar to a matrix $A$ that has a simple form. There are $4$ cases.

Case 1. $T$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity $3$. Then

$A=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1&0\\0&\lambda&1\\0&0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ is a Jordan block.

There are $2$ invariant subspaces $[e_1],[e_1,e_2]$.

Case 2. $T$ has $3$ distinct real eigenvalues $\lambda,\mu,\nu$. Then

$A=diag(\lambda,\mu,\nu)$ is diagonal.

The invariant subspaces are the direct sums of one or two eigenspaces. Then there are $6$ invariant subspaces.

Case 3. $T$ has a double real eigenvalue $\lambda$ and a simple one $\mu$. Then

$A=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1&0\\0&\lambda&0\\0&0&\mu\end{pmatrix}$ is in Jordan form.

There are $4$ invariant subspaces: $[e_1],[e_3],[e_1,e_2],[e_1,e_3]$.

Case 4. $T$ has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ and two conjugate complex eigenvalues $a\pm ib$, where $b\not= 0$. Then

$A=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&0&0\\0&a&b\\0&-b&a\end{pmatrix}$ is a simple block matrix (diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$).

There are $2$ invariant subspaces $[e_1],[e_2,e_3]$.

Comment: That's a right solution, the only problem is that this exercise appears before the Jordan form has been explained, so it is suppose to be solved without it. Anyway, thank you for the answer